# Parse Facebook Utils - Cannot resolve Parse

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

According to Facebook: Parse tutorials **4th Point**
https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-facebook-users

I followed it and removed the dependency com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3.

There is nothing in the libs folder as well. But all the code of using Parse library is now red giving an error - **Cannot resolve parse**

I am unable to understand, if the tutorials are incorrect ?

Comment: should work .. try 'clean' on proj. ... also review what gradle version used in the project and upgrade that if necessary

Comment: @RobertRowntree I have done that already and done it again. Also, I just downloaded the new Studio 2.0 Preview. So, I think gradle version is perfectly fine